# How to pass attributes to ListHDFS

Tags: apache-nifi

It seems, the way "list" processor works, we can't put them in middle of a flow. Then how to set attributes to ListHDFS? e.g. if I want to parameterize "directory", and pass it at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use expression language in the Directory property, but only to reference variables, system properties, or dynamic EL expressions, but not flow file attributes.

ListHDFS (and the other List processors) are made to track state and determine which files are new from the previous listing, so if you were allowed to specify the directory from an incoming flow file this would mean that the directory could change at any moment which then makes the previous state no longer meaningful, or would mean that it would need to track state for N number of directories which could grow large and would be unclear when a directory was no longer being listed.

It may be helpful to implement another processor that allows dynamic listings, but does not store state,

Comment: thanks. I guess my parametrize, i was thinking more of like global properties. (coming from j2ee background). No intention to change the basic idea of the processor. Just want not to touch it, once I go from test environment to prod environment.  I guess u answered it, (system properties). Or some better way? I am trying to see what is equivalent of application_resources.properties file of j2ee in Nifi

Comment: Ah I see, take a look at NiFi's variable registry concept, one is file-based in nifi.properties, the other is directly through UI https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/154951/introduce-a-ui-driven-variable-registry-starting-f.html

Answer (score 0):

In case, someone runs into this question, [GetHDFSFileInfo](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hadoop-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.GetHDFSFileInfo/index.html) would be what you are looking for.